# Unauthorized WebHook callback channel Google push notifications

Tags: google-drive-api, postman

I am trying to monitor my files in Google Drive.
By getting notifications to the delivery channel.
I've tried everything and tried hundreds of times but every time he tells me:
`

I am using Postman.

```
Post https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/changes/watch
Body:

  {"id": "01234567-89ab-cdef-012345***789ab",
  "kind":"drive#startPageToken",
  "type": "webhook",
  "address": "https://nwafith.com/api/notifications"
   }
```

Response

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "push.webhookUrlUnauthorized",
                "message": "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: https://www.nwafith.com/api/notifications"
            }
        ],
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Unauthorized WebHook callback channel: https://www.nwafith.com/api/notifications"
    }
}
```

In the Domain verification
**I added:**

```
www.nwafith.com

nwafith.com
```

Everything looks right but I don’t know exactly where the problem is.
I hope for help

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: I am using Postman

Comment: @DaImTo 
I can give you access to my device to try for yourself, I desperately need help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unauthorized WebHook callback channel:

Means that you have not properly authorized your domain in Google developer console.

Solution:

1. Go to the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/)
2. Select your project
3. Under 'APIS & AUTH' select 'Push'
4. Click 'Add domains'
5. Enter the needed domains (Only the domain is needed: https://www.nwafith.com)
6. Click the 'Add domains' button

After that it should work.

Comment: @DalmTo Thanks this is fixed